# Power BI - How to connect data with exact time in one dataset to a time range in other dataset

Tags: powerbi

Please, could somebody help me with my problem?

I have many XML files with call logs and one excel file with attendance of operators.

XML file contains ID of the phone, date of the call and some other stuff.

Excel file contains ID of the phone, date of the attendance of the operator, time from, time to (when the operator started and finished work that day) and the operator's name.

What I need is to add a new column in the XML files in Power BI and type in the name of the operator who managed the call. So it should search somehow the ID of the phone with the date and then check if the time is older or equal to the time "from" and simultaneously that the time is younger or equal to the time "to". If everything meets the conditions, then it should type in the column "name" the name from the row which met the conditions.

Is that possible in Power BI somehow? If it is, may somebody navigate me how to do that?

I hope it is because I need to automate this process fully (with no manual step like preparing CSV files) so I would be able to create reports from the data.

Thank You!!!

Tereza

Comment: Can you currently see the XML and Excel file as datatables with columns? I'm pretty sure you _can't_ do a "between" join when defining relationships between tables. You might be able to write DAX to join in this way. Perhaps take a look at this: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-joining-tables/ Data cleansing and integration only goes so far in Power BI. If you want to automate, you probably want to consider capturing and modelling the data in a data mart.

Comment: ... or this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c4e7a32d-fa51-48ae-bb5d-4b7f7c7421f6/merge-queries-where-date-is-between?forum=powerquery It's a technical question. You need to decide how much complexity you are happy embedding into Power BI